# My Eclipse installation/project broken - I can't get it working again

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have been away from my working project some months now and now I am encountering the following problems.

**Problem #1:**
When I started and start Eclipse it says:
"*This Android SDK required Android Developer Toolkit version 22.6.1 or above*"

What I tried to do:

- tried download all updates - no help
- tried download newewest Google ADT + download all updates no help (it currently states I have version 22.30.v201310242005--887826)

**Problem #2:**
It also claimed in project errors:
"cannot find java.object.lang"

I solved that by right clicking at project in "Package Explorer", went to Java build path and in "Libraries" I added JRE System Library. (I only had "*Android Classpath Container*", "*JRE System Library*", "*JUnit*", "*User Library*" available)

While it seems my solution solved that it now states
"*cannot find android.os.Bundle - fix the build path*"
and
"*The type android.os.Bundle cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files*"

**Problem #3**
Google-Play-Services reported errors. I have tried solving them, but ended removing it. When I try to re-add (Like Google documentation states) right-clicking on "*project - import*", "*Existing Projects into Workspace*" and select the directory whereto I copied the "google-play-services_lib" folder copied from SDK/extras, it just states no project file fouind.

**Problem #4**
After things I have done, my Package explorer no longer shows
Android.support-v4.jar

**Problem #5**
I also get error: Unable to resolve target "Google Inc:Google APIs:17 until the SDK is loaded.
I had more of these when I had android/support and google/play in project / package explorer.

It basically seems my installation is completely broken even though I have **not changed a single path**.

Can anyone here who knows Eclipse see through this mess and tell what is going on?

I imagine some of these issues are related.

Comment: Been there. Use IntelliJ.

Comment: Have you tried launching eclipse in clean mode ?

Comment: @Renato As backup solution, I am now ttrying to set that up as well. Of course it is complicated by the factt that I can not export my project from Eclipse :)

Comment: @Sandeep no difference in errors reported

Comment: @Tom Can you edit your post and add more details like: What are your OS/JDK/JRE/Eclipse versions,what's the first error message you see when you launch eclipse,what are your path and classpath settings ? How many projects are affected btw ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the initial problem #1 resolved:

stackoverflow.com/questions/22524789/error-this-android-sdk-requires-android-developer-toolkit-version-22-6-1-or-abo

And the rest has not seemingly resolved iself now

Answer (score 0):

You could try running eclipse in clean mode with `eclipse -clean`. That will cause it to first clear its caches.

Comment: This did not change anything :(